# How can I test a sender profile when doing a send preview or test send?

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to select a custom sender profile (not the default sender profile) when performing a Send Preview or Test Send? I am trying to test the dynamic sender alias we have set up.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes - within an email send you can preview your sending profile.  Go into your email studio and you'll see this as an option within a specific email.

[image]